# Switched byte order in result of glGetActiveAttrib in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I tried to compare output of glGetActiveAttrib (values type & size) against OpenGL constants and didn't get reasonable results. After some experiments I noticed that the byte order is switched, so this code:

```
    ByteBuffer auxType = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
    IntBuffer type = auxType.asIntBuffer();
    ByteBuffer auxSize = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
    IntBuffer size = auxSize.asIntBuffer();
    String name = glGetActiveAttrib(shader.program, 1, size, type);
    System.out.println(type.get(0));
```

outputs 1384841216. After re-ordering bytes I get 35666 (GL_FLOAT_VEC4) - that is correct. Same problem with size value. Is there any little-big endian switch in LWJGL or could it be issue with graphic card driver? I'm using LWJGL 3.1.1, graphics card is NVIDIA GTX 1060.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any little-big endian switch in LWJGL or could it be issue with graphic card driver?

It's actually all about the `ByteBuffer` itself. It has a byte order. So instead of creating the `type` `ByteBuffer` like this:

```
IntBuffer type = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4)
                           .asIntBuffer();
```

You create it and tell it the byte order:

```
IntBuffer type = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                           .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                           .asIntBuffer();
```

Also since you're using LWJGL, you can also use the static helper class `org.lwjgl.BufferUtils` and instead just do:

```
IntBuffer type = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
```

Now `type.get(0)` should correctly yield `35666` instead of `1384841216`. If you apply the same to `size`, then that should equally yield the assumed value.

Since you didn't supply a shader, I tested it with:

```
...
layout(location = 1) in vec3 position;
...
```

Then when calling `glGetActiveAttrib` it correctly yielded:

```
String name = glGetActiveAttrib(shader.program, 1, size, type);
System.out.println(name); // prints "position"
System.out.println(type.get(0)); // prints "35665"
System.out.println(size.get(0)); // prints "1"
```

Remember that `size` is just the element count of the array, so since we aren't dealing with an array it yields `1`.